# Unkown type name - possible circular dependency in C

Tags: c

I am having problems compiling my code. I am guessing it as circular dependency, but anyways my question is how to read the output gcc is telling me. I am getting something like this:

```
In file included from src/./../lib_ex/./../lib_ex/./../lib_ex/./../lib_ex/trav_item.h:7:0,
             from src_core/./../lib_ex/./../lib_ex/./../lib_ex/path.h:11,
```

And then one of the listed errors is something like this:
from

```
src_core/main.c:8: src_core/./../lib_ex/./../lib_ex/./../lib_ex/./../lib_ex/./../lib_ex/bubble.h:22:2: error: unknown type name ‘Path’
```

SO I am wondering where to check now the problem, as above it lists the headers path.h and trav_item.h but bellow mentioning another one bubble.h

So in my header path.h i have following entries (just shortened up to see if i indeed have a ciruclar dependency:

```
#include "./../lib_ex/trav_item.h"

struct Traversal_item;

typedef struct Path {

  int ID;
  char* ex;
  Traversal_item* ti;
}  Path;
```

In trav_item.h.i have this:

```
 #include "./../lib_ex/bubble.h"
 #include "./../lib_ex/path.h"

 struct Path;


 typedef struct Traversal_item {
   // some variables
   Path* path;
 } Traversal_item;
```

So I thought I have to predefine the struct path to be able to use it here, but apparently I am still doing something wrong :/.

Oh and in bubble.h I also include the path.header:

```
   #include "./../lib_ex/path.h"

   typedef struct {
     Path* path;
   } BBL;
```

Comment: You probably have some file (which you haven't shown) that includes one or more of those headers, but uses a struct when given only a forward declaration.  For example, to access a structs members, a forward declaration is not enough.

Comment: With interdependencies like that, wouldn't it be better to merge the three include files to one?

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
struct Path;
```

you are only making a forward declaration of the *structure* named `Path`, not the type-alias `Path`. Therefore using the type-alias will lead the error you have (as there is no *type* named `Path`).

There are two solutions: Either make a forward declaration of the type-alias

```
typedef struct Path Path;
```

Or in the `Traversal_item` structure use

```
struct Path *path;
```

The same thing with `Traversal_item` in the `path.h` header file.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. But Am i doing here something wrong about the structuring of the program? I thought, that you define your structurse in headers, and if you want to use them in a c file to include the header, right?

Comment: and another question, can I do this forward declaration also if in that header/c file the functions use some members of the structure, because then they are not defined yet :/